# Diagonalization of Hamiltonian in second quantization

Tags: hamiltonian, second-quantization

I am solving a problem from second quantization involving a Hamiltonian

$H=\hbar\omega a^\dagger a+\epsilon ab^\dagger  +\epsilon ba^\dagger$ ,

which needs to be diagonalized by using the transformation

$c=\alpha_1 a+\alpha_2 b$ ,

$d=\beta_1 a+\beta_2 b$ ,

where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are boson operators.

From the commutation relation I got

$\alpha_1^2-\alpha_2^2=1$

and

$\beta_1^2-\beta_2^2=1$.

Diagonalized form is

$H=E_1c^\dagger c+E_2d^\dagger d$ ,

so I have written the given Hamiltonian as

$H=a^\dagger a(E_1\alpha _1^2+E_2\beta _1^2)+ab^\dagger (E_1\alpha _2^* \alpha _1+E_2\beta _2^* \beta _1)+b a^\dagger (E_1 \alpha _1^* \alpha _2+E_2\beta _1^* \beta _2) +b^\dagger b(E_1\alpha _2^2+E_2\beta _2^2)$.

I got these sets of equations

$E_1\alpha _1^2+E_2\beta _1^2=\hbar \omega$ ,

$E_1\alpha _2^*\alpha _1+E_2\beta _2^*\beta _1=\epsilon$ ,

$E_1\alpha _1^*\alpha _2+E_2\beta _1^*\beta _2=\epsilon$ ,

$E_1\alpha _2^2+E_2\beta _2^2=0$ .

Is this the correct way? I don't know how to proceed from here on, and I would use some help!

The solution should be

$E_{1,2}=\frac{\hbar \omega}{2}\left ( 1\pm \sqrt{1+\frac{4\epsilon^2}{\hbar ^2\omega^2}} \right ) .$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, all the procedure is correct. Now youu just need to find the eigenvalues of your Energy matrix; those will correspond to the Energy values for the diagonalised system.

The Eigenvalues of a system are given by:
\begin{equation}
E\vec{v}=\lambda \vec{v},
\end{equation}
where E is your Energy matrix, $\vec{v}$ are the eigenvectors (the diagonalised states) and $\lambda$ are the Eigenvalues (Energy levels of the diagonalised theory). To solve for the Eigenvalues, you just need to solve the determinant of the substraction of the R.H.S to the L.H.S:
\begin{equation}
det(E-\lambda \mathbb{I})=0,
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity matrix. Therefore, plugging in the values, we find:
\begin{equation}
det\begin{pmatrix}
\hbar\omega-\lambda & \epsilon\\
\epsilon & -\lambda
\end{pmatrix}=0,
\end{equation}
which gives the second order equation:
\begin{equation}
\lambda^2 -\hbar\omega\lambda-\epsilon^2=0.
\end{equation}
As we said, the Eigenvalues of this system correspond to the Energy values of our diagonalised system. Therefore,solving that equation, we find:
\begin{equation}
E_{1,2}=\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{4\epsilon^2}{\hbar\omega}}\right).
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So, as I understand for now, E's are the eigenvalues of the coefficient matrix above. But, I am still having trouble understanding how this gives me the diagonalized form? I got the part about finding the eigenvalues of the matrix, but how to I make it from there to $H=E_1*c*c^†+E_2*d*d^†$ ?

Comment: Hi, I'm happy that it was helpful. To get the diagonalised Hamiltonian, you need to solve for the Eigenvectors (just sub into the first eq I wrote the Energy matrix and then solve for each eigenvalue). The vector $\vec{v}$ is in the basis $(a,b)$, and so you can relate the eigenvectors to $c$ and $d$. However, as $c$ and $d$ are symmetric, it doesn't matter which one is which. The final expression would look  as you said, but if you want to find $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1, \beta_2$ you need to calculate the eigenvectors.

Comment: I get
$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\hbar\omega & \epsilon\\ 
\epsilon & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)
\vec{v_1}=\lambda_1 \vec{v_1}$ and the same for $v_2$ and $\lambda_2$. I still don't see how will this get me to $\alpha$ and $\beta$. What would be the solution for the eigenvectors?

Comment: These maybe are the two eigenvectors, if I got it right
$v_{1,2}=\left [ \frac{\hbar\omega}{2\epsilon} \left ( 1\pm \sqrt{1+\frac{4\epsilon^2}{\hbar^2\omega^2}} \right ),1\right ]$, 
now what brings me from here to the diagonalized Hamiltonian?

Comment: The Eigenvectors I found are: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(E_1/\epsilon)^2}} (E_1/\epsilon,  1)$ , corresponding to the $E_1$ Eigenvalue (c state in you equation) , where the prefactor is for normalisation. And the other one will be symmetric as expected (given that H is symmetric), giving $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(E_1/\epsilon)^2}} (1,  E_1/\epsilon )$ , corresponding to the eigenvalue $E_2$, and so to the state d. To check if it's correct, you can solve the system of equations you derived for alphas and betas (they agree, I just checked). I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: You got to the right solution (it agreess with mine I think), but forgot to normalize. In Quantum Mechanics you must alwas work with normalised basis so you don't get probabilities being bigger than 1. Now these Eigenstates correspond to the d and c states you wrote in the diagonalised matrix, and also you know which eigenvector corresponds to each Eigenvalue. Therefore, $\vec{v_1}$ is the c state, and $\vec{v_2}$ is the d state; you see why? because that's how you defined each state in the diagonalised Hamiltonian Equation.

Comment: So from this, what are $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2, \alpha_1^*, \alpha_2^*, \beta_1^*, \beta_2^*$ equal to? I didn't get that part...

Comment: As the eigenvectors are in the base (a,b), you just need to expand them in the original basis and compare to the definitions you did. For instance, we know that the eigen v ectors are real, so $\alpha_i=\alpha_i*$. To get the exact value, $\alpha_1$ will be the first component of the $E_1$ eigenvector, $\alpha_2$ will be the second component of the $E_1$ eigenvector. The same applies for $\beta_i$ for the ith component of the $E_2$ eigenvectors. You can tell that they solve the constrains you impose in your equations, giving that $H=E_1c^\dagger c+ E_2 d^\dagger d$

Comment: Thank you very very much, I now understand and I managed to do the algebra! Thank you once again